# Preserving circular references after garbage collection

Tags: python, garbage-collection, weak-references, circular-reference

```
import weakref
import gc

class MyClass(object):
    def refer_to(self, thing):
        self.refers_to = thing

foo = MyClass()
bar = MyClass()
foo.refer_to(bar)
bar.refer_to(foo)
foo_ref = weakref.ref(foo)
bar_ref = weakref.ref(bar)
del foo
del bar
gc.collect()
print foo_ref()
```

I want `foo_ref` and `bar_ref` to retain weak references to `foo` and `bar` respectively as long as they reference each other<sup>*</sup>, but this instead prints `None`. How can I prevent the garbage collector from collecting certain objects within reference cycles?

`bar` should be garbage-collected in this code because it is no longer part of the `foo`-`bar` reference cycle:

```
baz = MyClass()
baz.refer_to(foo)
foo.refer_to(baz)
gc.collect()
```

<sup>* <sub>I realize it might seem pointless to prevent circular references from being garbage-collected, but my use case requires it. I have a bunch of objects that refer to each other in a web-like fashion, along with a `WeakValueDictionary` that keeps a weak reference to each object in the bunch. I only want an object in the bunch to be garbage-collected when it is orphaned, i.e. when no other objects in the bunch refer to it.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Normally* using weak references means that you cannot prevent objects from being garbage collected.

However, there is a trick you can use to prevent *objects part of a reference cycle* from being garbage collected: define a [`__del__()` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) on these.

From the [`gc` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.garbage):

> **gc.garbage**
>
> A list of objects which the collector found to be unreachable but could not be freed (uncollectable objects). By default, this list
>   contains only objects with `__del__()` methods. Objects that have
>   `__del__()` methods and are part of a reference cycle cause the entire reference cycle to be uncollectable, including objects not necessarily
>   in the cycle but reachable only from it. Python doesn’t collect such
>   cycles automatically because, in general, it isn’t possible for Python
>   to guess a safe order in which to run the `__del__()` methods. If you
>   know a safe order, you can force the issue by examining the garbage
>   list, and explicitly breaking cycles due to your objects within the
>   list. Note that these objects are kept alive even so by virtue of
>   being in the garbage list, so they should be removed from garbage too.
>   For example, after breaking cycles, do `del gc.garbage[:]` to empty the
>   list. It’s generally better to avoid the issue by not creating cycles
>   containing objects with `__del__()` methods, and garbage can be examined
>   in that case to verify that no such cycles are being created.

When you define `MyClass` as follows:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def refer_to(self, thing):
        self.refers_to = thing
    def __del__(self):
        print 'Being deleted now, bye-bye!'
```

then your example script prints:

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x108476a50>
```

but commenting out one of the `.refer_to()` calls results in:

```
Being deleted now, bye-bye!
Being deleted now, bye-bye!
None
```

In other words, by simply having defined a `__del__()` method, we prevented the reference cycle from being garbage collected, but any orphaned objects *are* being deleted.

Note that in order for this to work, you need circular references; any object in your object graph that is *not* part of a reference circle will be picked off regardless.

Comment: Of course, this is a giant hack and extremely implementation-specific. Other implementations likely don't have that "feature", and future CPython versions may lift it. I'd seriously consider reworking the code to not require this.

Comment: @delnan: No, this is actually not specific to the implementation; the garbage collection cannot determine the ordering of deletion here, and thus doesn't do it *at all*. This would apply to Jython and PyPy just the same.

Comment: The GC cannot determine which order makes the most sense, but it can pick an arbitrary order. [PyPy's GCs](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#differences-related-to-garbage-collection-strategies) do this, as a matter of fact. And the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6) explicitly declares the order of finalization unspecified, so I suppose JVMs have the same freedom (I wouldn't bet the correctness of my code on Jython taking steps to counter that).

Comment: @delnan: Right, interesting; so PyPy makes an explicit choice to call `__del__` anyway, even though that can break things, while CPython makes an explicit choice not to do so. I wasn't aware that PyPy had made that choice. :-)

Comment: +1, This is a clever solution though the design that requires it is questionable.